# Function vs Case efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Before your brain explodes yes i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284222/database-function-vs-case-statement).

My question is tailored to my specific situation. Im trying to optimize a very large database and im trying to rewrite some calls because it was converted from an Orical DB to a MS DB.

i have a function that is being called from a stored proc that i want to replace and i think it will be fine but im not sure in all cases.

this is the current function that is being called.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[GREATEST_DATETIME]
        (
         @i1_p  datetime,
         @i2_p  datetime
        )
returns datetime as

begin

    declare @r_l     datetime

    if @i1_p is null or @i2_p is null
        return null

    set @r_l = @i1_p
    if @i2_p > @r_l
        set @r_l = @i2_p

    return @r_l
end
```

I want to replace the call to the function entirely with this.

```
select CASE WHEN @date1 >= @date2 THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END
```

They both determine the largest date out of 2 dates im just not sure if im covering all my bases.

After testing

```
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime

set @date1 = '2015-05-01'
set @date2 = null

select CASE WHEN @date1 >= @date2 THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END
```

This returns null which is the desired result

Here is my final result that is going to work

```
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime

set @date1 = null
set @date2 = '2015-05-01'

select CASE WHEN @date1 is null or @date2 is null then null WHEN @date1 >= @date2 THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END
```

Comment: "My question is tailored to...."... But you ask no question. What is your question?

Comment: Other then the case where either is `null` yes it is equivalent.

Comment: RE: Your test try `set @date1 = null
set @date2 =  '2015-05-01'`

Comment: @MartinSmith SQL is a magical and unforgiving language

Comment: Scalar functions in t-sql are horribly inefficient. The case expression will perform much better on larger datasets.

Comment: For more complex logic, you should also compare performance of inline table functions, as far as I have seen, those perform quite good.

Comment: If you use inline table valued functions make certain they are one and only one statement. Otherwise they become multi-statement table valued functions and the performance tanks massively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of both dates are `null` then the first comparision will fail and return `false`. So you need the extra `null` check

```
select CASE WHEN @date1 is null or @date2 is null then null
            WHEN @date1 >= @date2 THEN @date1 
            ELSE @date2 
       END
```

Answer (score 2):

The new case statement here does not handle `NULL` in the same way as the original. The original would result in `NULL` if either source data was null.

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic defaults to NULL, your code should too.  The maintainers will thank you.

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN @date1 >= @date2 THEN @date1
  WHEN @date2 >  @date1 THEN @date2
  ELSE NULL
END
```